# Windows UWP PasswordVault Not Retrieving

Tags: uwp, winjs, windows

Ok, so I am new to UWP and testing out using the PasswordVault & PasswordCredential classes, but I can't seem to get it to work.

So here's my code:

```
    var Vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();
    var Credentials = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential();
    Credentials.resource = 'testResource';
    Credentials.userName = 'testUser';
    Credentials.password = 'testPass';

    var Add = Vault.add(Credentials);
    Vault.retrieveAll();

    console.log(Vault);
```

When outputting to the console, it has no resources. Oddly, this seemed to be working earlier, but no longer is. I have stripped it back to literally just the above, and created a new project to ensure nothing else was interfering. Where am I going wrong?

Edit:

I have looked inside the Windows Credentials Manager and found it is adding the credentials, so it's just the retrieving that's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cracked it! Clearly something stupid that I was doing. Above I stated that when I was trying to retrieve, I was doing:

```
Vault.retrieveAll();
console.log(Vault);
```

I was stupidly assuming that when the method called by the object, it would assign the result(s) as a property of that object.

The method actually just returns the result, so the below is what I actually needed to do:

```
var Credentials = Vault.retrieveAll();
console.log(Credentials);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the last time I used this, I always needed to provide a reference key to what I was storing and retrieving... Maybe that will help?

So

```
vault.Add(new PasswordCredential(Constants.VAULTRESOURCENAME, accountToAdd.UserName, accountToAdd.Password));
vault.FindAllByResource(Constants.VAULTRESOURCENAME);
```

Full details of my test : http://depblog.weblogs.us/2014/11/20/migrating-from-sl8-0-protectdata-to-rt8-1-passwordvault/

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately though, it doesn't work either. I've tried both methods "FindAllByResource" and "retrieveAll" but to no avail.

Comment: Yep. All documentation I have read outlines doing exactly what I am doing. I thought it was perhaps an issue with Visual Basic, but I tried a clean install.